# Figuring out the calling DOM object in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to figure out what element is creating an on click event in d3. Here is some sample code that I am using to test event handling:

```
g.selectAll("text")
    .data(allPoints).enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("class", "point-label")
    .attr("font-size", fontSize)
    .attr("cursor","pointer")
    .attr("id", function(d,i){
        return allPointData[allPoints.indexOf(d)][1] + "_name";
     })
    .text( function(d) { return allPointData[allPoints.indexOf(d)][1]; })
    .on("click", function(d) {
         // figure out what DOM element raised me
    });
```

So far, I have tried to do this:

```
.on("click", function(d) {
         alert("########### text with " + JSON.stringify(d3.event.target));
});
```

However, I am getting a weird value back with some data from the actual dom object, as opposed to the entire object itself.

```
########### text with {"__data__":[-122.2405556,37.7652778]}
```

UPDATE:
When I try : JSON.stringify(this) , I also get the same object

In reality, all that I am trying to do is figure out what element was called, and hopefully grab its ID. With this, I want to run some js code in my Scartchpad in firefox, to try and manually invoke the click function with actual code like:

```
document.getElementById("#element").click()
```

Comment: Why don't you use `this`?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado just tried it, and updated the question

Comment: Just use `this` without JSON.stringfy.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado you are right. Thanks. That worked. Put it in the answer so I can mark the question answered please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can figure out the calling DOM object using `this`:

```
.on("click", function(d) {
     console.log("my name is " + d3.select(this).text() + 
     " and my ID is " + d3.select(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ap1m1L0q/1/